# WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8)

Tags: django, linux, docker, nginx

> WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
> docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]].

I am facing this error on mac while trying to run this command `docker run --rm --gpus all -v static_volume:/home/app/staticfiles/ -v media_volume:/app/uploaded_videos/ --name=deepfakeapplication abhijitjadhav1998/deefake-detection-20framemodel`
How to solve this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing the command as

```
docker run --rm --gpus all --platform linux/amd64 -v static_volume:/home/app/staticfiles/ -v media_volume:/app/uploaded_videos/ --name=deepfakeapplication abhijitjadhav1998/deefake-detection-20framemodel
```

Please ensure that you have compatible Nvidia Drivers available as this application uses Nvidia CUDA.

Answer (score 61):

Put this line `--platform linux/amd64` after docker run. It works for me, using Macbook M1.

Comment: your answer is right but in my case, I was not aware that my GPU is not Cuda capable. is your GPU Cuda capable? Because In my M1 Macbook only a Built-in GPU is present.

Comment: No, I also have only built in GPU.

Comment: Oh Please try these two commands if it run successfully

Comment: Step 1: Install docker desktop and start the Docker daemon
Step 2: Run the deepfake detection docker image

`docker run --rm --gpus all -v static_volume:/home/app/staticfiles/ -v media_volume:/app/uploaded_videos/ --name=deepfakeapplication abhijitjadhav1998/deefake-detection-20framemodel`

Step 3: Run the Ngnix reverse proxy server docker image

`docker run -p 80:80 --volumes-from deepfakeapplication -v static_volume:/home/app/staticfiles/ -v media_volume:/app/uploaded_videos/ abhijitjadhav1998/deepfake-nginx-proxyserver`

Step 4: now go to http://localhost:80

Comment: can it not detect this automatically?

Comment: can you provide an example command? where does `--platform linux/amd64` does **exactly**?

Comment: is this correct? `docker run -v /Users/brandomiranda/iit-term-synthesis:/home/bot/iit-term-synthesis \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/pycoq:/home/bot/pycoq \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils:/home/bot/ultimate-utils \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/proverbot9001:/home/bot/proverbot9001 \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/data:/home/bot/data \
           -ti brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test bash
           --platform linux/amd64`?

Comment: Docker still has problems with the M1 chip so that's why we have to add linux/amd64 manually. 
Example command: docker run --platform linux/amd64 your-image-name
You can read more here:
https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6356

Comment: How do I adapt this to Docker Compose? `unknown flag: --platform`

Comment: can you show me your full command. what you are writing?

Comment: You can make this work for `docker-compose` too by using the `DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM` environment variable, e.g. `DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/arm64 docker-compose run [...]` @Under-qualifiedNASAIntern

Comment: ```DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64 docker-compose up --build```

Answer (score 3):

When you build the docker image, add the `--platform linux/amd64` flag and it will create an amd64 image instead of an arm64 image.

Comment: The following worked for me on my M1 `docker build -t <myuser>/<myimgage>:<tag> --platform linux/amd64 .  `

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo docker run --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=1' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=bigStrongPwd' -p 1433:1433 --name sqledge -d mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
```

Description :
*Be sure to change bigStrongPwd to a strong password of your choice. You can also change the value of the --name parameter if you wish.
By default, the container is run with the Developer Edition. You can run the Premium Edition by adding -e 'MSSQL_PID=Premium'.*

Src: [Database.guide](https://database.guide/how-to-install-sql-server-on-an-m1-mac-arm64/)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is correct:

```
docker run -v /Users/brandomiranda/iit-term-synthesis:/home/bot/iit-term-synthesis \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/pycoq:/home/bot/pycoq \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils:/home/bot/ultimate-utils \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/proverbot9001:/home/bot/proverbot9001 \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/data:/home/bot/data \
           --platform linux/amd64 \
           -ti brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test bash
```

since the warning I was getting went away.

Note, this gives a warning:

```
docker run -v /Users/brandomiranda/iit-term-synthesis:/home/bot/iit-term-synthesis \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/pycoq:/home/bot/pycoq \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils:/home/bot/ultimate-utils \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/proverbot9001:/home/bot/proverbot9001 \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/data:/home/bot/data \
           -ti brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test bash
           --platform linux/amd64
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
```

Answer (score 1):

The Owais Ali answer works for me.

I'm using Macbook with M2 chip, running SQL Server (that does not natively works on arm architectures) on Docker.

i've put this:

```
sudo docker run --platform linux/amd64 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=set_your_password_here" \
   -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 --hostname sql1 \
   -d \
   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I see, it seems like there's an architecture mismatch between the platform where you built the Docker image (M1 Mac) and the platform where you're trying to run the image (Ubuntu server, likely on AMD64 architecture).

#Enable experimental features in Docker

- export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled
- docker buildx create --name mybuilder
- docker buildx use mybuilder
- docker buildx inspect --bootstrap
- docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t
  your_image_name .
- docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t
  your_username/your_image_name --push .

Answer (score 0):

Create a build using the following command.

docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t my-node-app .

Answer (score -1):

WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95qEx.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34630251)