# Docker: exec /usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java: exec format error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, ktor

Image m2 works fine on macbook. It gives an error when I install and run it on Ubuntu.

command;

```
docker pull mademustafa/postmage:latest
docker run -it mademustafa/postmage:latest
```

Error;

```
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/arm64/v8) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and a specific platform was not requested
exec /usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java: exec format error
```

I did the installation according to the following documents;

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-20-04

https://ktor.io/docs/docker.html#build-run

(Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) x64)

Comment: That looks like you built an ARM-native image on your MacBook and are trying to run it on an Intel-based machine.  The processor instruction sets are different and you can't run one on the other.

Comment: These answers should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72448117/13963150, https://askubuntu.com/a/1418775

Answer (score 7, accepted):

solved;

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t madenmustafa/postmage --push .
```

Answer (score 3):

When you push the repository, you need use this code:

```
docker push --platform linux/amd64 mademustafa/postmage
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed to another base image of jdk11, and then fixed. Probably it was caused by different CPU architecture.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the platform issue. M1/M2 has arm based while the linux is amd based.

using `buildx` command docker helps in building images for multiple platforms.

I was able to resolve this issue by using the following command -

`docker buildx build --push --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t imagename -f Dockerfile .`