# exec /usr/bin/java: exec format error in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have installed kubernetes on arm64 server using kubespray.

I get error when I start pods:

```
root@node1:~# kubectl logs java-demo-788fbc87cc-j2s9r
exec /usr/bin/java: exec format error
```

Do you know how this can be fixed?

Comment: Install a java that's not damaged?  Install java that's compiled for arm64 rather than some other architecture?

Comment: I run `sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk` maybe this is the default one?

Comment: I see this: ` /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-arm64/bin/java` as a java home

Comment: Is that where /usr/bin/java points?   Can you run java on the host machine?  What java is installed in the java-demo image?

Comment: similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75089403/docker-exec-usr-local-openjdk-11-bin-java-exec-format-error

Comment: I also found it but I get ` -bash: docker: command not found`

Comment: can u also paste the output of the describe, at least the event list at the end of the log: kubectl describe pod <podName> (if it runs in specific namespace, kubectl describe pod <podName> -n <namespaceName>)

Comment: here it is: https://pastebin.com/svBKSSLu

Comment: from your log, you are using fstab/java-demo (https://hub.docker.com/r/fstab/java-demo/tags). It is created to run on Linux/Amd64, not Arm64. First of all, if your K8s node (node2/10.0.0.207) has Arm64 architecture, you should create docker image for arm64. Or you should use another K8s node with Amd64, not Arm64. Creating docker image for multiple architecture: https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-images/

Comment: First try this docker container with `Docker` - the question is not related to Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, if you cannot change the PC (from arm64 to amd64), you can create your docker image with this:

Sample Docker Image:

```
# FROM arm64v8/ubuntu:20.04
# or use a base image suitable for both ARM64 and AMD64 architectures
FROM --platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64 ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jre

# Copy your Java application JAR or files
COPY your-app.jar /app.jar

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

**REF:** https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/

```
docker buildx install
docker buildx build --push --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t your-image-name:tag .
docker run -d your-image-name:tag  # please test on both amd64 and arm64
```

**REF:** https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/#cross-compilation

You should build on the Arm64 device. On the reference above (cross-compilation), you can list the builder on Arm64:

```
docker buildx ls
```

Please read the cross-compilation reference in detail.

Comment: Is it correct to configure `FROM --platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64 openjdk:17-slim-buster`?

Comment: like this:  https://github.com/rcbandit111/mockup/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: I checked the dockerhub for openjdk: https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/tags?page=1&name=17-slim-buster if FROM --platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64 openjdk:17-slim-buster doesn't work, please try (adding linux/arm64/v8) FROM --platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64/v8 openjdk:17-slim-buster